# How can I augment an interface type that I cannot modify in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

When I attempt to augment an interface in Typescript, I get this error:

```
'BasketballPlayer' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

For example:

I have a `BasketballPlayer` type in a library which I cannot modify.

```
interface BasketballPlayer extends Player {
    run(speed: number): boolean
}
```

When creating a `BasketballPlayer` instance, I would do something like this:

```
const playerFactory = new PlayerFactory();

// The PlayerFactory returns the base Player type.
// I will then need to cast the returned instance to the BasketballPlayer type.
const basketballPlayer = playerFactory.getPlayer("BasketballPlayer") as BasketballPlayer;
```

I want to add an additional function called `dunk` on the `BasketballPlayer` type whenever it's instantiated. Here's what I do:

```
declare module "./generated/library" {
    interface BasketballPlayer {
        dunk(strength: number): Promise<boolean>;
    }
}

// However, Typescript will complain that "'BasketballPlayer' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.""
// But I cannot augment PlayerConcrete instead because only BasketballPlayer will have `dunk`, not all Player(s).
BasketballPlayer.prototype.dunk = async function(strength: number): Promise<boolean> {
    // Do the dunk logic
    return true;
}
```

Since I don't have control however the library files, how else can I augment the `BasketballPlayer` interface type? I'm quite sure it will always have an actual instance of it when used with the `BasketballPlayer` interface.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr The prototype augmentation is only appropriate if the underlying subject is a class not an interface. An interface does not exist in JavaScript (i.e. will be compiled away at runtime), whereas a class is a construct that will carry a prototype object in JavaScript and can thus store things like function definitions to be used at runtime

---

From your description it appears we have the following interfaces + classes defined in your 3rd party library

`library.ts`

```
interface Player {
  name: string // abritrary property added for demo purposes
}
class PlayerConcrete implements Player {
  name: string = ''
}

interface BasketballPlayer extends Player {
    run(speed: number): boolean
}
```

If you were just interested in overriding the interface itself, your initial module re-declaration logic would be sufficient:

`augment.ts`

```
import { BasketballPlayer } from './generated/library'

declare module "./generated/library" {
    interface BasketballPlayer {
        dunk(strength: number): Promise<boolean>;
    }
}
```

`component.ts`

```
import { BasketballPlayer, PlayerConcrete } from './generated/library'
import './augment.ts'

class BasketballPlayerConcrete extends PlayerConcrete implements BasketballPlayer {
  run = (speed: number) => // do the run logic;
}
// Error: Property 'dunk' is missing in type 'BasketballPlayerConcrete' but required in type 'BasketballPlayer'.(2420)

class BasketballPlayerConcrete extends PlayerConcrete implements BasketballPlayer {
  run = (speed: number) => // do the run logic;
  dunk = (strength: number) => // do the dunk logic;
}
// valid

const basketballPlayer: BasketballPlayer = new BasketballPlayerConcrete()
```

As there is no existing `BasketballPlayerConcrete` class defined in your `library.ts`, there is no need to override any prototypes as you will be defining your class (and thus the `dunk` function's implementation) in another file which you control, e.g. `component.ts`. However, if `BasketballPlayerConcrete` did exist in `library.ts`, we could continue with the approach you had used

`library.ts`

```
// ... same as previous
class BasketballPlayerConcrete extends PlayerConcrete implements BasketballPlayer {
  run = (speed: number) => // do the run logic;
}
```

`augment.ts`

```
// ... same as previous
import { BasketballPlayerConcrete } from './generated/library'

BasketballPlayerConcrete.prototype.dunk = function(strength: number): Promise<boolean> {
  // do the dunk logic
}
```

`component.ts`

```
import { BasketballPlayer, BasketballPlayerConcrete } from './generated/library'
import './augment.ts'

const basketballPlayer: BasketballPlayer = new BasketballPlayerConcrete()
```